# Pseudo-full screen in Chrome iOS patched out

Tags: javascript, ios, css, google-chrome, chrome-ios

In previous builds of Chrome, it was possible to create a pseudo full screen effect which is retained for the duration of a user's session (until the user scrolls up or otherwise interacts with the browser chrome) by requesting the user scrolls contents. This would then minimise the amount of chrome (ui) displayed to the user, providing additional viewport space to see contents.

If the user navigates to another page, the chrome continues to be presented in its minified state.

At the company I am working with, we used this to great effect for a web-based magazine reader which fills the entire screen (no scrolling) and is optimised for smaller viewports. The user could press a button which would display a scrollable overlay which would hide the chrome after the user scrolled the content. As the user navigates to different pages, the URL changes so that the user can share pages naturally and resume from where they left off.

However, this effect seems to be no longer possible to achieve in Chrome on iOS.

Although the chrome minifies on scroll as expected, the chrome is now reset to its non-minified state each time the URL in the address bar changes, even if it is just an anchor which changes (such as `page.html#p1` to `page.html#p2`).

Other browsers remain are unaffected (including Safari on iOS and Chrome on Android, the latter of which has a native full screen mode).

Was this mistakenly or intentionally patched out?

If intentional, is there a workaround which permits full screen which won't require a dramatic rebuild such as by changing our user experience to accommodate that single configuration?